# Border Image Confusion

Tags: css

I wish to have an image for a top border. I've looked into this and used various online border builder tools but I'm still confused how to make a border for top only.

Here is what I have:

```
border-image:url('test.png') ???? repeat;
border-bottom:0;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
```

I have an image that is 50px by 50px and I want this to repeat x across a top border. I have left question marks in the above code as this is the part I do not understand. I know this is to do with the slicing of the image, but I do not need my image sliced, I just want it to repeat.

Comment: Have you tried the doc? : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Comment: @YoannAugen W3schools is no where close to being an official documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: @Terry Neither is Mozilla!